# Is there a way to put php inside of a IE conditional comments

Tags: php, internet-explorer, wordpress, conditional-comments

I have a php section that loads jquery through wordpress from google's api. I dont want to load jquery on IE browsers. Long story short, it doesn't work for whatever reason (you can read through my other posted questions).

Or if this is not possible is there another way to NOT use this code when its an IE browser, maybe a php solution.

```
<?php 
    if( !is_admin()){
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js', false, '1.5.2', true);
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }

?>
```

Targets everything except IE (what i was trying to use, but it didnt work):

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You'd probably want to detect the browser in a PHP block as an alternative solution. Something like:

```
$browser = get_browser();
if ($browser->browser == 'MSIE') {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js', false, '1.5.2', true);
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}
```

Or using the `$is_IE` global variable as in Nikolay Yordanov's answer:

```
if ($is_IE) {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js', false, '1.5.2', true);
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}
```

Comment: well specifically, if($is_IE){...stuff...} else { ...insert jquery stuff...} OR IF this works if(!$is_IE){...insert jquery stuff...}

Comment: well i had a misunderstanding, i found out that you have to declare teh variable as global first: global $is_IE; thanks again

Answer (score 4):

You have the global $is_IE in Wordpress.

Comment: Indeed, use that as the conditional rather than the conditional comments.  Alternatively you can use the conditional comments but you'll have to write out the script tag yourself instead of using the WordPress wp_register_script calls.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: IE conditional comments are client side, while PHP is server side, so it won't work.

Possible solution: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php  (or according to one of the answers already posted, wordpress provides a $is_IE global)